# Edit functionality position

Tags: usability, gui-design, material-design, best-practice, edit

I've got the following listing page where a user could click on a list item and a secondary panel would slide out from the right as seen on the second wire-frame. The edit button here is a primary action where a user could do much more changes to a list item.

My question is, is it better to have the edit button inside the slide out section? or is there a better way in approaching the edit functionality?

furthermore If you could point out any UX related errors, I would be glad to fix them.

**Application Listing Wireframe**

[image]

**Application listing with expanded view**

[image]

Comment: What about placing the edit function inside each row at the end (right side after status) and make it visible as soon as the user hovers over each row? 

I would keep the edit in the expanded view as well since its the only action.

Comment: What information does your edit button allow you to edit?

Comment: It has much more complex edit functionalities such as release management, info, package management and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If editing is a common operation, you shouldn't hide the edit button behind a slide-out.

As Don Norman says in [The Design of Everyday Things](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/design-everyday-things-0):

> In each state of the system, the user must readily see and be able to do the allowable actions.
>
> **The visibility acts as a suggestion reminding the user of the possibilities**.

Comment: So as a proper location could I use the listing it self to show the edit functionality?

Comment: That is correct. Placing an Edit button/label at the beginning or end of each row would work.